# D3 Not ordering x axis correctly

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

I'm quite new to programming, but i'm trying to create a D3.js Stack bar graph displaying data over a few decades, but my values are automatically being ordered, I wish for them to be chronologically displayed on the X axis like my database. (1960-69 ordered to 2010-2019) How do I change this?

[image: screenshot of my current chart]

```
<style>

.axis .domain {
  display: none;
}

</style>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([0, width])
    .paddingInner(0.25)
    .align(0.1);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(['#9452a5','#548aef','#c26c86','#fab294','#7edcd3','#f27280','#c4cecf']);

d3.csv("data.csv", function(d, i, columns) {
  for (i = 1, t = 0; i < columns.length; ++i) t += d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
  d.total = t;
  return d;
}, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var keys = data.columns.slice(1);

  data.sort(function(a, b) { return b.total - a.total; });
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Type; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })]).nice();
  z.domain(keys);

  var bars = g.append("g")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(d3.stack().keys(keys)(data))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); })
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return d; })
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data.Type); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); })
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth());
  
  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null, "s"))
    .append("text")
      .attr("x", 2)
      .attr("y", y(y.ticks().pop()) + 0.5)
      .attr("dy", "0.32em")
      .attr("fill", "#000")
      .attr("font-weight", "bold")
      .attr("text-anchor", "start")
      .text("North Korean provocations");

  var legend = g.append("g")
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("font-size", 10)
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(keys.slice().reverse())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 19)
      .attr("width", 19)
      .attr("height", 19)
      .attr("fill", z);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9.5)
      .attr("dy", "0.32em")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });
});

</script>
```

Comment: You may need to use the [Sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Syntax) method at some point

Comment: Your code is sorting by the `total`; you could sort by `Type` or skip sorting if your data is already ordered correctly.